# When must a character save against a creature's inhaled poison?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When a creature has the *poison* special ability, an inhaled poison is listed, and none of their attacks list poison as an effect, when must a creature save vs the poison?

Comment: Which creature is this?

Comment: @Rob from the Bestiary 3, and I don't have it in front of me at the moment.  Starts with an A, looks like a giant puffball fungus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it depends on the monster, the answer is probably somewhere in its stat block.

Take the [fungal lizardman's](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/fungal-lizardfolk) inhaled poison - it's listed as an Aura on the fourth line of the statblock.  In this case, the [standard inhaled poison rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison) apply, you have to save the second you enter the area (though you can attempt to hold your breath). As opposed to the [Tatzlwyrm's](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/tatzlwyrm) inhaled poison, where it's listed as a special breath-type thing that requires an action, in which case you'd save when it breathes it on you.

EDIT: Based on your further comment you mean the [Ascomoid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/ascomoid).  That's pretty straight forward, it says straight out how its spore-poof works and you only have to save against the spores' poison if you fail the nausea save from the spores attack.  You'd save immediately and then of course each turn thereafter until you shake it off (2 saves or 6 rounds, whichever comes first).

Comment: I see @C.Ross doubt: beyond being explicitly stated in the Spores special attack, the Ascomoid's stat block refers to a Poison special attack. Being there, the immediate thought is that Poison is an active option for the ascomoid (not only a consequence of another special attack). You must read the entire description to find out that it is not.